# Whether kafka cluster non-flushing disk mode could take effect for certain topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I want Kafka cluster to support quasi real-time message transform(< 500 ms), do I need to set the Kafka cluster to the non-flushing disk mode? If I set non-flushing disk mode, Whether non-flushing disk mode could takes effect for certain topics? not for all the topics, because other topic I need high reliability for consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Kafka is not forcing fsync during messages processing, you can change it on the topic level by setting of configuration properties:

- [flush.messages](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_flush.messages)
- [flush.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_flush.ms)

Comment: I reduce flush messages and flush.ms on my servers, now i want reduce message latecy from 500ms to 100ms(from Java client send to Java consumer received), but the average delay only can reach 137ms, is there any other way to reduce the latency in order to make latecy less than 100 ms? tks.

Comment: I have got 8ms latecy on my server, based on this web page: https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/kafka-fastest-messaging-system/, tks.